# Large font-size in a text-input breaks out of container

Tags: css

I have a text input wrapped inside a inline element which adds some padding and border.  But when I increase the font-size the input grows beyond the containing element.

`display:flex-inline` seems to fix it, but I don't think that has good IE support?

http://jsfiddle.net/3hyjd/1/

How can I make the height of the container automatically adjust?  Preferably with IE<9 support.

Answer (score 1):

a cleaner approach will be to alter your DOM a little bit, so the support will be from all browsers, without any hack.

see that <kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/3hyjd/5/)</kbd>

**HTML:** (span instead of div)

```
<span class="field">
    <input type="text" />
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.field {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

input {
    font-size:1.3em;
}
```

but, If you cant alter your DOM, use `inline-block` for the `field` instead of `inline`.

in that case, you'll need to apply some fix for it to work in IE6,IE7.

See that <kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/3hyjd/3/)</kbd>

**HTML:** (same as yours)

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.field {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    /*fix for IE6,IE7*/
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}

input {
    font-size:1.3em;
}
```

Comment: what * in display means? is it a css hack or its a valid css?

Comment: @imsiso it targets only IE below 8.

Comment: +1 - and is it a valid css? and/or is it a css hack?

Comment: this is **invalid** CSS syntax. It's an IE hack. The second declaration will be applied by IE7 and older (thus overriding the first declaration), while other browsers will ignore it and continue applying the first declaration instead.

Comment: so if I use that my CSS will not be a valid CSS what should I do instead to have a valid CSS?

Comment: @imsiso Its a known trick and it can be use without any problem. you can treat it **as if** it was valid.

Comment: I know but sometimes the customer wants me to give him a valid CSS and they will not accept it if it doesn't pass CSS validation test. What is a general way to solve this kind of problems without CSS hack? again thank you.

Comment: @imsiso IE6/7 apply `inline-block` on `inline` elements, the hack is only for `block` elements. so in your case, I would not use the hack, instead I would change the `div` to a `span`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem setting a max-width:100% to the input. I mean:

```css
input {
  max-width:100%
}
```

It works cross browser